# GeoPandas imports NULL attribute values as zeros from shapefile

Tags: shapefile, fields-attributes, geopandas, import, null

I would read a shapefile as GeoPandas DataFrame using:

```py
import geopandas as gdp

df = gdp.read_file('file.shp')
```

When I read the file, the `NULL` values have been loaded as zero. I need to see and distinguish null values and the real zeros.

Comment: What is GeoPandas' version? Could you share your shapefile or part of it containing null values?

Comment: The main issue is in the shapefile format https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000005811. Change to something better.

Comment: Shapefile does not support numeric nulls. It doesn't support nulls at all, but empty strings are usually interpreted as nulls. Since it is not possible to store null vales, your problem is in the attempt to write nulls in the first place.

Comment: `GeoPandas 0.7.0` and `GeoPandas 0.9.0`. The same for gpkg files.

Comment: Do you see NULLs if you open the GeoPackage with QGIS or with some generic SQLite client? Could you share some sample data as GeoPackage?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/giactitti/ExampleData) shp and gpkg sample of my data. I can see the features with null attributes on QGIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around the problem. First I export the GPKG as CSV adding a column with explicit geometry, then I load with Pandas the CSV table as a DataFrame. Now the `NULL` cells are still `NULL`.